# Should you convert or only assign a color profile when wanting to preserve color appearance?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, cmyk, color-conversion, color-profile

**Context:** 
I am preparing a design to be sent off to a professional printer. I will print the exact same design on both coated and uncoated paper, requiring FOGRA39 and FOGRA47 respectively.

In InDesign, I have set up a document including this color: CMYK(0,0,0,10), a light grey.

My workspace profile for CMYK is FOGRA39. When manually checking the PDF-X, the color is correctly defined as CMYK(0,0,0,10). When assigning and converting the PDF-X (during my InDesign export) to FOGRA47, the color changes to CMYK(7,5,5,0).

**Question:** 
When assigning and converting colors from one profile to another during export, is InDesign trying to achieve color appearance? Or should I only assign the color profile to achieve the same color appearance on both versions of the printed product?

***EDIT*** 
The goal is the achieve "the same" color appearance on both papers.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: What is your goal? Shall the output on uncoated and coated paper look the same?

Comment: @StefanBollmann Yes, the goal is to have the same color appearance on both papers. Obviously, the color shift between profiles seems to be quite subtle here, but I would like to know in general, when more significant differences between profiles exist, how do keep the same color appearance on different types of paper?

Comment: @DerGoliHerr what you describe can be one of many things. You might be using a perceptual or saturation, intent. See color management si not really all that complicated IF you can make the same colors, the problem is rather what happens when you can not.